# Non-empty iterator over regex groups becomes empty array

Tags: regex, scala, iterator

I have this strange situation - when I print regex groups to a console, they show up. When I convert this iterator to array - it's empty. Following code doesnt print anything:

```
val str = "buy--751-rates.data"

val expr = "--(.+)-rates.data".r

val target = Array[String]()
expr.findAllIn(str).matchData map(m => m group 1) copyToArray(target, 0, 4)
target foreach { println }
```

But this snippet works:

```
val str = "buy--751-rates.data"

val expr = "--(.+)-rates.data".r
println("Scala matches:")
expr.findAllIn(str).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m group 1)
}
```

I guess I missed something simple

Comment: What about `expr.findAllIn(str).matchData map(m => m group 1) foreach { m => println(m) }`? Does it behave strange too?

Comment: What about using `expr.findAllIn(str).matchData foreach { m => target :+ m }` instead of the penultimate line in the first code snippet?

Comment: @bash0r your solution works. actually, what I'm after is getting first element of that, but there's no head method on Iterator

Comment: If you are after the first match, why not use `findFirstIn`?

Comment: @RedLaser that doesnt work for me - still empty array

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both findFirstIn and findAllIn give me just one result - the whole string. I would like second group, that's why I use `m group 1`

Comment: Do you happen to mean [`--(\d+)-rates\.data`](https://regex101.com/r/oX5dN8/1) ? This would yield `751`.

Comment: Ehm... What size does the array have before you copy? I could imagine that the copy doesn't alter the size of the array leaving it to an array with zero elements... I'm currently installing Scala so please be patient. ^^

Comment: Could you get the map then convert it to array using `.toArray` then set that to `target`?

Comment: @bash0r I created an array of 10 elements, but the regex match doesnt show in there

Comment: @RedLaser tried that, compilation fails with "not enough arguments for method toArray"

Comment: @Jan yeah, but the thing is - it might have letters in this position

Comment: I think the regex can be `"""--([^-]+)-rates\.data""".r` here. Unless the captured value can contain `-`. Then, only lazy matching is an alternative: `"""--(.*?)-rates\.data""".r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't get anything because you were copying to a zero length array. You don't actually need to do that as there is a toArray method on the iterator that converts it to and array and from that you can get the head value if you want. For example:

(expr.findAllIn(str).matchData).map(m => m group 1).toArray.head

Comment: Same as my tests were showing. The array is just empty because it's empty from the beginning. :D

Comment: ok, thanks guys, I thought I was crazy. any reason why `.toArray()` call on an `Iterator` didnt not work?

Comment: correction - it works exactly as Al wrote it, without the braces. so I can do `iterator.toArray.something` but not `iterator.toArray().something`?

Comment: @chester89 because it does not need the round brackets